# How to change the partition scheme

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I want to change the partition scheme in my 500 GB HDD from MBR to GPT scheme without losing DATA on it. What are the traditional tools to do this on both windows 7 and Linux(ubuntu)? And what are the necessary  steps to do this?

Comment: How many partitions does the entire drive have?

Comment: I have two partitions on it with 200 GB unallocated space.

Comment: Step 1: do a full backup. Step 1A: test backup. Step 2: repartition. Step 3: restore, if needed